# why not delete 0.0 here?

Tags: python, backpropagation

```
 downstream_delta = reduce(
        lambda ret, conn: ret + conn.downstream_node.delta * conn.weight,
        self.downstream, 0.0)
```

I wanna know why there exists 0.0. The self.downstream here is a list, why not just delete 0.0, and let self.downstream elements accumulate?

Comment: This avoids an error in case `self.downstream` is empty, and `0.0` is a value you want in that case.

Comment: you mean the first parameter in the list is set to 0.0 and the datatype should be float?

Comment: Consult [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)

Comment: THX! fully understood!